# Given any infinite set $A$, there is an bijection on $A$ which does not fix any element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By fix any element, I mean $f(x)\ne x$ for all $x\in A$. I saw this question in Pinter's Set theory book and I'm wondering if my answer is correct. This question was in an exercise after the section where Zorn's Lemma was discussed.

---

My attempt:
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of bijective functions on **subsets** of $A$ which do not fix any element. Clearly $\mathcal{P}$ is nonempty because we can pick two different elements $a_1$ and $a_2$ from $A$ and we can consider the function which sends $a_1$ to $a_2$ and $a_2$ to $a_1$. Now, consider $\mathcal{P}$ as a partially ordered set with inclusion as the partial order.

We invoke Zorn's Lemma to show the existence of such a function. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a chain in $\mathcal{P}$. Now, we claim that $h = \bigcup \mathcal{C}$ is an upper bound for $\mathcal{C}$. But for that, we need to first how that $h$ is a bijection on some subset of $A$. Let $D=\bigcup \left\{ B\subseteq A \, : \, (\exists f\in \mathcal{C}) (f\text{ is a function on } B)\right\}$. It is not too hard to see that $h$ is a function from $D$ to $D$.

We now show that $h$ is a bijection. Let $\langle x_1,y \rangle,\langle x_2,y \rangle \in h$. Then $\langle x_1,y \rangle\in f$ and $\langle x_2,y \rangle \in g$ for some $f\in \mathcal{C}$ and some $g\in \mathcal{C}$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain, we may assume $f\subseteq g$ and so $\langle x_1,y \rangle\in g$. Since $g$ is one to one, $x_1=x_2$. Now we show that $h$ is onto. Let $y\in D$. There is some $B\subseteq A$ satisfying that there is a function $f\in \mathcal{C}$ on $B$ and $y\in B$. Since $f$ is onto, $\langle x , y \rangle \in f$ for some $x\in B$. So, $\langle x , y \rangle \in h$. This shows that $f$ is onto. Now, if $h$ fixed some element in $D$, then there must be some function in $\mathcal{C}$ which would fix an element but that is not possible. So,this shows that $h$ is an upperbound for the chain $\mathcal{C}$. Thus, there must be a maximal element $f\in \mathcal{P}$.

Now, we claim that $f$ is a function on $A$. Suppose not, there must be some $a\in A$ which is not element of $\operatorname{dom} f$. Now, pick an element $a' \in \operatorname{dom } f$. Then consider the function $g$ on $\operatorname{dom } f \cup \{ a\}$ such that $g(a)=f(a')$, $g(a')=a$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\ne a, a'$. Clearly, $g$ is a bijection and $f\subsetneq g$ which is a contradiction that $f$ is maximal. So, $f$ is a function on $A$ which does not fix any points.

---

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1):

No; the argument breaks down in the last step.  Note in particular that $f$ is actually *not* contained in $g$, since $g(a')=a$ is different from $f(a')$ (which must be an element of $\operatorname{dom} f$ since $f$ is bijection from $\operatorname{dom} f$ to itself).  Moreover, $g$ is not a bijection, since there is some element $b\neq a'$ of $\operatorname{dom} f$ such that $f(b)=a'$, and then $g(b)=a'=g(a)$ so $g$ is not injective.

In fact, it is not necessarily true that $f$ is defined on all of $A$.  If $f$ were defined on all of $A$ except for just one point $a$, then $f$ would still be maximal: any proper bijective extension of $f$ would have to fix $a$, since there is nowhere else you can map $a$ to.

Comment: It was too huge a mistake to be overlooked. Is there any way I could possibly fix this by changing $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to fix it, but off the top of my head, I don't see any *direct* way to use Zorn's lemma (i.e., a use of Zorn's lemma to a poset consisting of bijections on subsets such that a maximal element is then defined on all of $A$).  Instead, you'll probably want to do a more indirect argument: first use Zorn's lemma to get some maximal element that is close to the bijection you want, and then modify it in some small way to make it actually a bijection defined on all of $A$.

Comment: @AshishK: The simplest modification that comes to mind is to let $C=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N$ be a countably infinite subset of $A$ and take $\mathcal{P}$ to be the set of bijections on subsets of $A\setminus C$. A maximal element element of $\mathcal{P}$ will then be defined on all of $A$ except $C$ and possibly one point of $A\setminus C$, and in either case the problem is essentially reduced to finding a permutation of $\Bbb N$ with no fixed points.